# Formatação DataHora

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, formatação

Tenho um campo no banco de dados DataHora, minha classe é simples e não tem annotation

```
public DateTime DataHora { get; set; }
```

eu tenho estes dois campos na tela para o usuário que usará um único campo no BD

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataHora, "Liberar às", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataHora, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control TextoTextBox", id="hora", DataFormatString = "{hh:mm}" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataHora, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataHora, "Liberar dia", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataHora, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control TextoTextBox", id = "data", DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" } })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataHora, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
</div>
```

eu queria saber o que eu preciso fazer para que estes dois campos na tela possa utilizar um único campo da classe e do banco, pois quando tiro o focus(clico em outro lugar) ele exibe está mensagem de erro:

> The field DataHora must be a date.

e outra coisa que eu notei é que o padrão da data, não permite que eu insira o formato brasileiro, apenas o americano, porém fiz a validação usando o

> DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"

no EditorFor (ao final dos campos).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ei Fabio, tive mesmo problema, fiz um pequeno tutorial: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/227756/54019