# Globalize - datetime não funciona com pt-BR

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, datetime

Favor, segue código:

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = 
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);    
}
```

**Web.config:**

```
  <system.web>    
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
  </system.web>
```

**Model:**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Data:")]
[AssertThat("DeadLine >= Today()", ErrorMessage = "* Data deverá ser superior a data de hoje")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo Data é obrigatório")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? DeadLine { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
@model Projeto.Models.Teste

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Teste";
}

<h2>Teste</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Home", "Index", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DeadLine, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeadLine, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <input type="submit" value="Test" />
}



@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script src="~/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/date.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Use $.getJSON instead of $.get if your server is not configured to return the
// right MIME type for .json files.
    $.when(
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/main/pt/numbers.json"),
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/main/pt/ca-gregorian.json"),
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/main/pt/timeZoneNames.json"),
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/supplemental/timeData.json"),
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/supplemental/weekData.json")
).then(function() {

  // Normalize $.get results, we only need the JSON, not the request statuses.
  return [].slice.apply( arguments, [ 0 ] ).map(function( result ) {
      return result[ 0 ];
  });

        }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
            //Globalize.locale("pt");
            //Globalize.culture("pt-BR");

});

</script>

}
```

Resultado final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu digitar 12/08/2017 funciona ok. Agora se eu digitar depois do dia 12, ou seja, 13/08/2017. mostrar aviso vermelho. Parece que está invertido, padrão americano. Não consigo definir padrão brasileiro.

O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TUTORIAL: COMO CONFIGURAR GLOBALIZE EM SEU PROJETO VS2017**

Vou fazer um pequeno tutorial aqui, porque foi muito complicado fazer ela funcionar:

Site oficial globalize: https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize

Primeiro você deve instalar [jQuery.Validation.Globalize](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation.Globalize/) no seu projeto, dentro dela, possui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1. cldrjs
2. jquery-globalize
3. jQuery.Validation.Globalize

Feito isso, precisa baixar mais uma coisa: **CLDR**, pois **Globalize** usa o CLDR , o maior e mais extenso repositório padrão de dados de localidade.

Quando você instala jquery-globalize, não vem a parte **CLDR** no seu projeto. Você precisa fazer isso manualmente. Aqui está documentação dele:

> We do NOT embed any i18n data within our library. However, we make it
>   really easy to use. Read How to get and load CLDR JSON data for more
>   information on its usage.

Então você precisa usar executar esse comando:

```
bower install cldr-data
```

Esse arquivo tem 242 MB !!! Ele possui todas linguagem. Feito isso, vamos configurar a data para pt-BR.

Na sua View, adiciona um pequeno código javascript:

```
<!--CLDR-->
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>

<!--Globalize-->
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/date.js"></script>

<!--Validate-->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Use $.getJSON instead of $.get if your server is not configured to return the
// right MIME type for .json files.
    $.when(
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/main/pt/numbers.json"),
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/main/pt/ca-gregorian.json"),
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/main/pt/timeZoneNames.json"),
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/supplemental/timeData.json"),
        $.get("/Scripts/cldr-data/supplemental/weekData.json")
).then(function() {

  // Normalize $.get results, we only need the JSON, not the request statuses.
  return [].slice.apply( arguments, [ 0 ] ).map(function( result ) {
      return result[ 0 ];
  });

        }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
            Globalize.locale("pt");
});

</script>
```

Como uma alternativa para deduzir isso você mesmo, use esta [ferramenta online](http://johnnyreilly.github.io/globalize-so-what-cha-want/#/?currency=true&date=true&message=true&number=true&plural=true&relativeTime=true&unit=true). A ferramenta permite que você selecione os módulos que você deseja usar e lhe informa os arquivos Globalize e o JDRON CLDR que você precisa. No meu caso é só data:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, só testar o campo data !!! Espero que isso ajude outros. Fique a vontade para editar minha resposta, caso você deseja melhorar.

OBS: Não precisa configura nada no arquivo **web.config**.