# Renomear mensagem de erro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, localização

Segue *model*:

```
[DisplayName("Data:")]
[ValueParser("ptdateparser")]
[AssertThat("DeadLine > Today()", ErrorMessage = "* Data deverá ser superior a data de hoje")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo \"Data\" é obrigatório")]
```

Eu tenho o campo que valida a data, eu recebo o seguinte de aviso:

> The field "Data" must be a date.

Como posso renomear esse aviso?

Ex:

> O campo "Data" deve ser uma data.

Answer (score 4):

A s configurações da máquina deveria estar em português, então resolveria. Se não puder fazer isto pelo menos a língua precisa estar instalada, e precisa configurar para usar nossas mensagens:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
```

Ou ainda configurar:

```
<system.web>
   <globalization responseEncoding="UTF-8"
                  requestEncoding="UTF-8"
                  culture="pt-BR"
                  uiCulture ="pt-BR"
                  enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
   .....
</system.web>
```

Ainda pode usar um arquivo de recursos novo configurando o `Global.asax` secção `Application_start`:

```
ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "PtbrResources";
```

2
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "PtbrResources";

Aí crie um `PtbrResources.resx` com as mensagens de erro que deseja. procure no arquivo padrão por `FieldMustBeDate The field {0} must be a date."

[image: Aba com edição de arquivo de recurso]

Se ainda quiser personalizar a mensagem tem alguns caminhos, um deles:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "O campo \"Data\" deve ser uma data")]
```

Uma solução mais completa e programática pode ser achada em um [blog da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mvpawardprogram/aspnetcore-mvc-error-message?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Outro artigo](http://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/).

É possível fazer via biblioteca no cliente, talvez usando jQuery se for o caso que está usando. precisará isntsalr os componentes para isto:

```
PM> Install-Package jQuery.Validation.Globalize
PM> Install-Package jquery-globalize
```

Tem um rapaz que [respondeu isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227624/101), veja se resolve o que deseja.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/TranslateErrorMsg.cs).

Comment: @MatheusMiranda editei.

Comment: Eu mesmo fiz :), o que eu quero é somente renomear aviso.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver dessa maneira:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "form-control", data_val_date = "Personaliza a sua mensagem aqui !"})
```

Ou pode tentar dessa maneira:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new
{
    @class = "form-control",
    data_val_date = String.Format("O campo '{0}' deve ser uma data válida, verifique.",  
                                    Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date))
})
```

Comment: Isso não resolve o mesmo problema, resolve outro. Pra resolver esse eu teria respondido isso.